# How to get an image embedded in a Word document to my desktop?

Tags: microsoft-word

How to get the properties of word document images?

Is there anyway to get the image in word document set to my desktop background image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i got the result, by saving the files as html. I got all the images in the separate folder.

Thanks a lot for all user.

Answer (score 4):

If your Word document is in .docx format you can get to the full size embedded image by opening the file as an archive. An easy way to do this is using the free [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Right-click the Word file and select `'7-Zip > Open archive'` 
Open the 'word' folder and then 'media' to see the embedded images.
Copy the image to a folder then right-click and select 'Set as desktop background'.

Comment: I finally got another correct way.

Comment: I only wish it was as easy with regular .doc files

Answer (score 3):

You can also Right-Click on the image, and select `save as picture` (Word 2007+); Then navigate to the image using Explorer and Right-Click on it and select `set as desktop background`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit cumbersome

- Open the word document
- Left click on the image so it's selected
- Right click the image and select copy
- Open paint (or any other image application you are familiar with)
- Paste in the image
- Crop the image
- Save the image with an appropriate name
- Right click the saved image and select "set as desktop background"

Comment: image not getting proper resolution in this.